# Undefined property '$M_Auth'.intelephense(1014) on Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4, intelephense

I'm going to make login page, but it keep telling me `Undefined property '$M_Auth'` when I'm trying to define my model, it's work well in my last project, but now when I open the last project this message is also occurred.

This is my Auth Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use App\Models\M_Auth;

class Auth extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->M_Auth = new M_Auth();
    }
    public function index(){
        echo form_open();
        return view('Auth/login');
    }

    public function cek_login(){
        if($this->validate([
            'username' => [
                'label' => 'Nama Pengguna',
                'rules' => 'required',
                'errors' =>[
                    'required' => '{field} tidak boleh kosong!'
                ]
            ],
            'password' => [
                'label' => 'Kata Sandi',
                'rules' => 'required',
                'errors' =>[
                    'required' => '{field} tidak boleh kosong!'
                ]
            ] 
        ])){
            //jika valid
            $username = $this->request->getPost('username');
            $password = $this->request->getPost('password');
            $cek = $this->M_Auth->login($username, $password);
        }else{

        }
    }

}
```

This is M_Auth model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class M_Auth extends Model
{
    protected $DBGroup          = 'default';
    protected $table            = 'pengguna';
    protected $primaryKey       = 'id_pengguna';
    protected $useAutoIncrement = true;
    protected $allowedFields    = ['level_id', 'username', 'password'];

    public function login($username, $password){
        return $this->db->table('pengguna')->where([
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password
        ])->get()->getRowArray();
    }

}
```

Idk what's wrong, tried to fix it by watch tutorial on ytb but it doesn't have any different than my code and already search here too but i don't really understand the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
class Auth extends BaseController
{
    private M_Auth $M_Auth;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->M_Auth = new M_Auth();
    }
    public function index(){
        echo form_open();
        return view('Auth/login');
    }
   ...
```